# How to display videos, if its out of public_html in php

Tags: php, video

For security reason, I moved all the videos to out of public_html, but I can't able to view the video in my webpage. Is there is any API to view videos in out of public html? or is there any other way in php?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use PHP to "route" the videos out. Something like [`readfile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Comment: The video file downloading, but is it possible to play it in webpage?

Comment: As long as you're providing correct headers, there's not much differences between downloading and playing.